# OLS and the Method of Moments estimator

Tags: least-squares, method-of-moments

I have been taught that the Method of Moments Approach could be used to obtain estimates of a bivariate regression of the form y = B0 + B1x + u.

Specifically, the 2 Moment conditions are E(u) = 0 and E(xu) = 0.

However, I fail to see how these are moment conditions. Which distribution are these 2 conditions moments of ?

I read that the definition of moments of a distribution are expectations of the powers of the random variable. But the 2 conditions above are not powers of a random variable ?

Comment: A moment does not require that you know the distribution; many distributions have an expected value, as in $\mathbb{E}(u) = 0$, for example, the Gaussian distribution, the Laplace distribution, the Gamma distribution...  and the second condition merely states that the $x$ and $u$ are uncorrelated with each other.

Comment: But which distributions are the parameters B0 and B1 drawn from ? Will it be the distribution of Y ?

Comment: $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are not drawn from any distribution(s); they are parameters and, unless you are performing a Bayesian analysis, which you aren't, are considered fixed. The only random term in your expression is $u$.

Comment: Hmm okay I understand what you are saying, how then are moment conditions generated ? From my (textbook) understanding, moment conditions are generated by using deriving the moment conditions from the pdf of the underlying distribution.

Comment: If you are estimating the parameters of a distribution, yes.  In your case, you aren't, you're estimating $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ in a linear regression.  You want to find $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ such that the sample moment conditions hold (equating sample moments to population moments is the heart of method of moments.)  So, you want to find $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ so that the sample mean of the $u$ equals zero, and similarly for the sample mean of $xu$.

Comment: I have changed the title writing out Method of Moments, as there is also a robust MM-estimator for regression, which is something else.

Comment: Hi: I'm not sure but you might be alluding to the generalized method of moments ( GMM ) which is similar to the method of moments but uses a a weighting matrix. There is a lot of literature on this method ( came out in the early 80's ) and was developed by Hansen who is an econometrician. So, I'm not totally sure that this is what you are referring to.